# Virtualizazion: vSphere compatibility with AMD motherboards and graphic card

Tags: virtualization, vsphere

Xen and Xenserver do not want to work with AMD motherboard and graphic cards. VMs (whatever the operating system we are trying to spin) will not work if I try to pass-through a Tonga XT GL [FirePro S7150], even experts from Citrix have not been able to help! After a lot of frustration I have decided to give a go to vSphere virtualisation based on VMWare. Do you know if it will work with the Graphic card we are using. Can you suggest a good tutorial that will direct me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by going through the Hardware Compatibility List to ensure it is supported first: https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php